# Django Float Field input

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-widget, form-fields

Which is the best way to create a django form field that accepts floats and has the same functionality as a NumberInput? What I mean with same functionality is that django's NumberInput has arrows right next to the input that can increase or decrease the number and it also accepts min_value and max_value. If I use a TextInput widget I won't get this functionality. If I use NumberInput widget it wont work with floats:

```py
homework = forms.FloatField(
    required=False, max_value=10, min_value=0, 
    widget=NumberInput(
        attrs={'id': 'form_homework'}
    )
)
```

[image]

It doesn't include floats (i.e 5.5) when I click the + - buttons. Also, it doesn't show the float at all if I want to set the actual float (the homework's grade) as an initial value (using Jquery).

Any advice is welcome.

EDIT:

If I do:

```py
class NumberInput(TextInput):
    input_type = 'number'

homework = forms.FloatField(
    required=False, max_value=10, min_value=0,
    widget=NumberInput(
        attrs={'id': 'form_homework', 'step': '0.1'}
    )
)
```

The 'step' attribute works but the max_value/min_value doesn't. If I do not define NumberInput that way and use the regular NumberInput, it doesn't work at all.

Comment: you will likely have to find a javascript that will implement this feature; there are a number that you can use that give options for what the up/down arrow will do (i.e. set the "step" size, i.e. 0.10 or 1.0, etc).

Comment: So.. yes I guess I can do with with Js, but I was wondering if there is a django widget or something.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this by including NumberInput with your form widget and setting step attribute

```py
homework = forms.FloatField(
    required=False, max_value=10, min_value=0, 
    widget=forms.NumberInput(
        attrs={'id': 'form_homework', 'step': "0.01"}
    )
)
```

Difference from above answer is missing forms reference with NumberInput of form

Answer (score 5):

Just specify "step" attribute as a widget attribute, this way:

```py
homework = forms.FloatField(
    required=False, max_value=10, min_value=0, 
    widget=NumberInput(
        attrs={'id': 'form_homework', 'step': "0.01"}
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It doesn't work though. Please look at the Edit.

Comment: I think @matagus was suggesting to use `django.forms.NumberInput`, not create your own input with that name.

Comment: For anyone wondering on @thespacecamel that means editing the code to look as follows - `widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs=`

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this by including TextInput with your form widget

```py
homework = forms.FloatField(
    required=False, 
    widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'type': 'number', 'id':'form_homework', 'min': '0', 'max':'10', 'step':'0.01'}
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [forms.NumberInput](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/forms/widgets/#numberinput) as shown below, then all work properly:

```py
from django import forms

homework = forms.FloatField(
    required=False, max_value=10, min_value=0,
    widget=forms.NumberInput(
        attrs={'id': 'form_homework', 'step': 0.1}
    )
)
```

In addition, this code below also works properly:

```py
from django import forms

homework = forms.FloatField(
    required=False,
    widget=forms.NumberInput(
        attrs={'id': 'form_homework', 'max': 10, 'min': 0, 'step': 0.1}
    )
)
```