# How to increase or decrease FloatField by 1000 with it's default button?

Tags: python, django

I have a FloatField in my models. The increase and decrease buttons on the right side of this area normally increase or decrease by 1 each. Is it possible to do this 1000 by 1000? How can I do that?

**models.py**

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    ...
    credit_limit = models.FloatField(default=0, null=True)
    ...
```

**forms.py**

```
class NewCustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('customer_name', 'country', 'address', 'customer_number', 'phone_number', 'email_address',
                  'credit_limit', 'currency_choice')
```

to be clear:

[image: to be clear]

Comment: Try to use `step`, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27949510/django-float-field-input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the [**`step="…"`** attribute [w3schools]](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_step.asp) of the `<input type="number">` field, so with:

```
class NewCustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = …
        widgets = {
            'credit_limit': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'step': 1000})
        }
```